# Retreiving unadorned Action name from within the Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an action method:

```
[Area("Waffles")]
public class WafflesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/waffles/edit/{id?}", Name = nameof(EditView))]
    public IActionResult EditView( int id ) {
        ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

In other views/actions I can retrieve the URL (`/waffles/edit`) of this with either:

```
url = urlHelper.Action(nameof(WafflesController.EditView));

url = urlHelper.RouteUrl(nameof(WafflesController.EditView));
```

Inside the view/action itself however both calls return the URL & path parameter, i.e. at `http://me.com/waffles/edit/1234` both `UrlHelper` methods return `"/waffles/edit/1234"`, is there a way for me to return just `"/waffles/edit"` as I can from elsewhere?

**Edit**

To clarify, inside the view launched from the action above `urlHelper.RouteUrl(nameof(WafflesController.EditView));` returns the route URL + its `id`: `"/waffles/edit/1234"` I want just `/waffles/edit/` in a string.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way for me to return just "/waffles/edit"

To hide the id in url, you can use **ajax get and TempData** to achieve:

View:

```
<a href="waffles/edit" id="1234">Edit</a>
 
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("a").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "get",
                data: { "id":  id },
                success: function () {
                    window.location.href = url;
                },
            })

        })

    </script>

}
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet("/waffles/edit", Name = nameof(EditView))]
public IActionResult EditView(int? id)
{
    if (id == null && TempData["Data"] != null)
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Data"]);
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Data"] = id;
    }

    return View();
}
```

### Update

> I need /waffles/edit in a string within the view (without its id)

Just try this code:

```
 string url = "/waffles/edit/1234";
 url = url.Remove(url.Length - (url.Split('/')[3].ToString().Length + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a misunderstanding I think - this is not about hiding the URL, I need `/waffles/edit` in a string within the view (without its `id`).

Comment: @Olmy, I'm sorry I misunderstood what you mean, if you just want to split the url string, then you can use the `Split` and `Remove` method to achieve, I have updated my reply.